# Jsoup Java For Loops and Elements

Tags: java, parsing, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm learning jsoup for use in java.  First of all, I'm not really understanding what the difference is between jsoup "Elements" and jsoup "Element" and when to use each.  Here's an example of what I'm trying to do.  Using this url http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_bow_tie_wearers#Architects I want to parse the text names under the category "Architects". I've tried this:

```
Document doc = null;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_bow_tie_wearers").get();
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
    Elements basics = doc.getElementsByClass("mw-redirect");

    String text = basics.text();

    System.out.println(text);

}
```

Here is the output:

```
run:
Franklin Roosevelt Arthur Schlesinger, Jr. Reagan administration University of Colorado at Boulder Eric R. Kandel Eugene H. Spafford Arthur Schlesinger, Jr. middle finger John Daly Sir Robin Day Today show Tom Oliphant Today show Harry Smith TV chef Panic! At The Disco Watergate Watergate Hillary Clinton Donald M. Payne, Jr. Franklin Roosevelt Baldwin–Wallace College Howard Phillips Twilight Sparkle Gil Chesterton Bertram Cooper Richard Gilmore Dr. Donald "Ducky" Mallard, M.D., M.E. Medical Examiner Brother Mouzone hitman Buckaroo Banzai Conan Edogawa Jack Point Waylon Smithers Franklin Roosevelt NFL Chronicle of Higher Education Evening Standard
```

I'm really just trying to learn the basics of traversing a HTML document but I'm having trouble with the jsoup cookbook as it is confusing for a beginner.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding your first question, the difference between Elements and Element is, as the names indicate, the number of items.

An object of type Element contains one HTML node. One of type Elements multiple.

If you take a look at the constructors in the api documentation for [Element](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html) and [Elements](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html), it becomes rather obvious.

Now for the parsing part. In your code you are looking for "mw-redirect", wich is not enough. You need to first "navigate" to the correct section.

I've made a working sample here:

```
Document doc = null;
try {
    doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_bow_tie_wearers").get();
} catch (IOException e) {

}

if (doc != null) {

    // The Architect headline has an id. Awesome! Let's select it.
    Element architectsHeadline = doc.select("#Architects").first();

    // For educational purposes, let's see what we've got there...
    System.out.println(architectsHeadline.html());

    // Now, we use some other selector then .first(), since we need to
    // get the tag after the h3 with id Architects.
    // We jump back to the h3 using .parent() and select the succeding tag
    Element architectsList = architectsHeadline.parent().nextElementSibling();

    // Again, let's have a peek
    System.out.println(architectsList.html());

    // Ok, now since we have our list, let's traverse it.
    // For this we select every a tag inside each li tag
    // via a css selector
    for(Element e : architectsList.select("li > a")){
      System.out.println(e.text());
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention, the last for loop implicitly uses "Elements". Just in case you didn't notice, .select() itself returns a list of elements of type Elements. :-)

Comment: Thank you. I know this is very basic info, so I appreciate you taking the time for the explanation.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I was wondering if there was a way to include or exclude certain things. For instance, the output of this prints out the word "Harvard" since it is included in text in one of the `a` elements at the end of "Walter Gropius" section. Another example, the last name in the list, "Owen Luder" is not included since we selected the nextelementsibling of the "Architect" header. It appears that "Owen Luder" is not in the same unordered list as the rest, and was tacked on later. Finally, I also don't know how we could get the dates and descriptions that are nested in there.

Comment: Now you're getting to the interesting part. ^^ First of all, you're right, there is a second unordered list. So we would need to perform the same stunt again to get Owen as well. Then, to parse the date after the name you would have to make some sort of freetext parsing. Either using regex or some other tricks. If you need help on this just tell me. Something realy important when parsing websites is: As long as they are not under your control, the scraper you build needs constant maintenance. There is no way around this. When the website changes, most of the time you need to change your code.

Comment: The thing with HTML is, just because a human can process the information which is shown doesn't mean a computer can parse it. Most of the time this isn't even intended by the site admin. There are a few things which can make life easier, like getting the source using selenium, checking for changes you have to reflect in your code and handing it to JSoup afterwards. (JSoup is used in this scenario because Selenium is dead slow when it comes to data extraction)